# How do I make an API call before the DOM component renders using svelte?

Tags: svelte

In Svelte, onMount is normally used to make an API call. I wanted to make an API call before the DOM component is rendered. What can I use for that?

I tried using beforeUpdate which I was thinking renders the DOM elements after the block of code inside beforeUpdate is ran. But it is not so. So, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the API call in `onMount` like you suggested and use an `{#if expression}` block to only render the component when the API call has resolved.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3282c2841e1248b69d6a4ba545e9d7be?version=3.8.1))**

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  function getData() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ foo: 1, bar: 2 });
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  let data;

  onMount(() => {
    getData().then(response => {
      data = response;
    })
  })
</script>

{#if data}
  <div>Foo: {data.foo}</div>
  <div>Bar: {data.bar}</div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://svelte.dev/docs#await giving you a bit more flexibility over rendering before it has resolved and eventual error handling

```
<script>
    function getData() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
               resolve({ foo: 1, bar: 2 });
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

    let data = getData();
</script>

{#await data}
    <p>
        hold on, loading data...
    </p>
{:then value}
    <div>Foo: {value.foo}</div>
    <div>Bar: {value.bar}</div>
{/await}
```

Comment: Follow up on this one: How would you do this when `getData` is called in `onMount`, which is the [recommended way of loading data](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount)? I'm especially interested in how you would handle errors.

Comment: @Flavio Sure, `OnMount()` is run *after* the component is rendered, but that doesn't change anything. To adhere to this recommendation, we can declare `let data` in the script, then define data later like `onMount(()=>{data=foo()});`. Finally, we can respond to the data being in various states as suggested using `#await`, `:then`, & `:catch`.